# Fill a column based on groups and conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Consider the below Pandas `DataFrame`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Make': ['Tesla','Tesla','Tesla','Toyota','Ford','Ford','Ford','BMW','BMW','BMW','Mercedes','Mercedes','Mercedes'],
                   'Type': ['Model X','Model X','Model X','Corolla','Bronco','Bronco','Mustang','3 Series','3 Series','7 Series','C-Class','C-Class','S-Class'],
                   'Year': [2015, 2015, 2015, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2020, 2015, 2015, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2020],
                   'Price': [85000, 90000, 95000, 20000, 35000, 35000, 45000, 40000, 40000, 65000, 50000, 50000, 75000],
                   'Color': ['White','White','White','Red','Blue','Blue','Yellow','Silver','Silver','Black','White','White','Black'],
                   'Code'  : ['TSLABG','TSLA',None,'TYTA','FRD','_BG',None,None,'BMW','BMW','MercedesBG','Mercedes_BG','MercedesBG']
                  })
```

```
df
     Make   Type       Year Price   Color   Code
0   Tesla   Model X    2015 85000   White   TSLABG
1   Tesla   Model X    2015 90000   White   TSLA
2   Tesla   Model X    2015 95000   White   None
3   Toyota  Corolla    2017 20000   Red     TYTA
4    Ford   Bronco     2018 35000   Blue    FRD 
5    Ford   Bronco     2018 35000   Blue    _BG
6    Ford   Mustang    2020 45000   Yellow  None
7     BMW   3 Series   2015 40000   Silver  None
8     BMW   3 Series   2015 40000   Silver  BMW
9     BMW   7 Series   2017 65000   Black   BMW
10 Mercedes C-Class    2018 50000   White   MercedesBG
11 Mercedes C-Class    2018 50000   White   Mercedes_BG
12 Mercedes S-Class    2020 75000   Black   MercedesBG
```

I am trying to update the `Code` Column based on the `Make` Column if `Code` column is having `None`, it must be  correctly filled based on the other values of  `Code` column for the same `Make`. In other words if any `Make` is having `Code` defined in the `Code` column that value should be used to fill `None` value in the `Code` column, also if  `BG` or `_BG`  is appended to any code value of the same `Make`, all the `Code` values should be appended with the `BG` or `_BG` respectively  for the same `Make` .

Since `BMW` is having no `BG` or `_BG` for already existing `BMW` code values, when replacing the None it doesn't get appended with `BG` or `_BG`. For Ford `_BG` is present for one of the values and `FRD` is present for another value so all `Code` values of `Ford` should be `FRD_BG`.

For Mercedes there are `Code` values with `BG`  appended to the Code, so if any `Code` value is having `_` prepended to the `BG`, the `_` should be removed from the `Code` Value

The code I have tried

```
code = (df['Code'].str.split('(_)', expand=True).add_prefix('part').replace('-', None).groupby(df['Make']).transform('first').fillna('').agg(''.join, axis=1))
df['Code'] = code
df
```

The output I got has MercedesBG_BG but I was expecting MercedesBG

```
     Make   Type       Year Price   Color   Code
0   Tesla   Model X    2015 85000   White   TSLABG
1   Tesla   Model X    2015 90000   White   TSLABG
2   Tesla   Model X    2015 95000   White   TSLABG
3   Toyota  Corolla    2017 20000   Red     TYTA
4    Ford   Bronco     2018 35000   Blue    FRD_BG
5    Ford   Bronco     2018 35000   Blue    FRD_BG
6    Ford   Mustang    2020 45000   Yellow  FRD_BG
7     BMW   3 Series   2015 40000   Silver  BMW
8     BMW   3 Series   2015 40000   Silver  BMW
9     BMW   7 Series   2017 65000   Black   BMW
10 Mercedes C-Class    2018 50000   White   MercedesBG_BG
11 Mercedes C-Class    2018 50000   White   MercedesBG_BG
12 Mercedes S-Class    2020 75000   Black   MercedesBG_BG
```

The expected output is:

```
     Make   Type       Year Price   Color   Code
0   Tesla   Model X    2015 85000   White   TSLABG
1   Tesla   Model X    2015 90000   White   TSLABG
2   Tesla   Model X    2015 95000   White   TSLABG
3   Toyota  Corolla    2017 20000   Red     TYTA
4    Ford   Bronco     2018 35000   Blue    FRD_BG
5    Ford   Bronco     2018 35000   Blue    FRD_BG
6    Ford   Mustang    2020 45000   Yellow  FRD_BG
7     BMW   3 Series   2015 40000   Silver  BMW
8     BMW   3 Series   2015 40000   Silver  BMW
9     BMW   7 Series   2017 65000   Black   BMW
10 Mercedes C-Class    2018 50000   White   MercedesBG
11 Mercedes C-Class    2018 50000   White   MercedesBG
12 Mercedes S-Class    2020 75000   Black   MercedesBG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split by `(BG|_BG)` **instead of** `(_)` to get the desired results:

```
code = (df['Code'].str.split('(BG|_BG)', expand=True).add_prefix('part').replace(
    '-', None).groupby(df['Make']).transform('first').fillna('').agg(''.join, axis=1))
df['Code'] = code
```

`df`:

```
        Make      Type  Year  Price   Color        Code
0      Tesla   Model X  2015  85000   White      TSLABG
1      Tesla   Model X  2015  90000   White      TSLABG
2      Tesla   Model X  2015  95000   White      TSLABG
3     Toyota   Corolla  2017  20000     Red        TYTA
4       Ford    Bronco  2018  35000    Blue      FRD_BG
5       Ford    Bronco  2018  35000    Blue      FRD_BG
6       Ford   Mustang  2020  45000  Yellow      FRD_BG
7        BMW  3 Series  2015  40000  Silver         BMW
8        BMW  3 Series  2015  40000  Silver         BMW
9        BMW  7 Series  2017  65000   Black         BMW
10  Mercedes   C-Class  2018  50000   White  MercedesBG
11  Mercedes   C-Class  2018  50000   White  MercedesBG
12  Mercedes   S-Class  2020  75000   Black  MercedesBG
```